# Equivalent of Task.FromResult() from .NET 4.5 in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, task

I cant find information about retargeting my code from .NET 4.5 to 4.0. I have to install this application on Windows XP.

my code in .NET 4.5

```
public async Task <IXLWorksheet> ImportFile(string fileToImport)
{
    ...
    return await Task.FromResult<IXLWorksheet>(Sheet1)
}
```

In .NET 4.0 method FromResult does not exist.
Someone knows how it should looks in .NET 4.0??

Comment: Add [`Microsoft Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) to project packages.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx check this and also in .Net 4 you can't use async/await from what I remember

Comment: Still same problem.

Comment: The code for that method is just `return new Task<TResult>(result);`. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,11a386e7d7cae64a  So, I'd think you can just do `return Sheet1;` there regardless of which version of .Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the awaited result of a task, which is constructed on a result. The solution is rather simple - drop the `await`:

```
return Sheet1;
```

The `async` keyword in the method declaration will take care of wrapping it in a task.

If, for some reason, you need to manually wrap an existing value in a completed task, you can use `TaskCompletionSource` - it's a bit clunkier than `Task.FromResult`, but just a bit.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem with `TaskCompletionSource`, here's my code:

```
 public async Task <IXLWorksheet> ImportFile(string fileToImport)
        {
         ...
                TaskCompletionSource<IXLWorksheet> tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<IXLWorksheet>();
                Task<IXLWorksheet> t1 = tcs1.Task;
                tcs1.SetResult(tempFile.Worksheet(1));
                return await t1 ;
        }
```