# what is the equivalent of Task.FromResult() from .NET 4.5 in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, .net-3.5, titanium-web-proxy

I'm using the titanium proxy to analyse the data trafic.

They using Task.FromResult(0) as return. My environment it was 3.5 framework.

```
 m_proxyServer.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += OnCertificateValidation;
```

what can we use replace for Tasks.FromResult(0) in .NET3.5 framework, Because my environment works in 3.5 framework only.

```
public Task OnCertificateValidation(object sender,CertificateValidationEventArgs e)
    {           
        //set IsValid to true/false based on Certificate Errors
        e.IsValid = true;         

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

I have gone through the question [40422779](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422779/equivalent-of-task-fromresult-from-net-4-5-in-net-4-0), But I cannot able to use async since its only .NET 3.5.

Comment: Why are you using Task without Async?  All your code will be synchronized anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired from [Link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,ddcbcd3aba23c5a9)

I have created a new class and named as Tasks and implemented the following

```
public static class Tasks
{
    public static Task<TResult> FromResult<TResult>(TResult result)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        tcs.SetResult(result);
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task WhenAll(Task[] tasks)
    {
        return Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (t) => t);
    }

    public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        new Timer(_ => tcs.SetResult(null)).Change(millisecondsDelay, -1);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Then I changed the main method as

```
 public Task OnCertificateValidation(object sender,CertificateValidationEventArgs e)
{           
    //set IsValid to true/false based on Certificate Errors
    e.IsValid = true;         

    return Tasks.FromResult(0);
}
```